# how to check if argument is a string or int

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have wrote a function `getResult()` that has only one parameter.

- If the attached argument is of type `Int`, then the value returned is the value of the argument multiplied by 5.
- If the attached argument is of type `String`, the value returned is a character length.
- If the attached argument is of type other than `Int` and `String`, then the returned value is 0.

How can I write `getResult()` so it returns 6?

```
fun main() {
    val stringResult = getResult("Kotlin")
    val intResult = getResult(100)

    println(stringResult)
    println(intResult)
}

fun <T> getResult(args: T) {
    // ???
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: And what does it return now? Add this to question. Why 6?

Comment: 6 defines the length of the word "kotlin", why 6? because what is read first is "kotlin" which is a string. the question is, what code can be put into fun <T> getResult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
fun getResult(args: Any?): Int =
    when (args) {
        is Int -> args * 5
        is String -> args.length
        else -> 0
    }
```

Comment: i try to change my code:
```fun <T> getResult(args: T) {
    when (args) {
        is String -> args.length
        is Int -> args * 5
        else -> 0
    }
}```
but when i run it will come out 'kotlin.Unit'. what's the main problem?

Comment: @VelvetCrowe add a `return` statement before the `when` expression and add `Int` as return type to your function OR copy Andrei's function (which uses an expression body)

Comment: You don't need `reified` (and `inline`) here, since you are not accessing the type.

Comment: @Willi Mentzel exactly! Thanks for noticing

Comment: @Velvet Crowe you have to can add `return` or replace `{ }` with `=`. Or just copypaste my function :)

Comment: @AndreiTanana I just noticed, you don't even need generics. You could simpliy use `Any`. :)

Comment: @WilliMentzel definitely!